# how to get the expression in an operator in maple?

Tags: maple

I am deriving an HJB type PDE with Maple like this:

```
eq1 := diff(U(t, q), t) + lambda*sup(h(delta)*(U(t, q - 1) - U(t, q)) + (1 - h(delta))*(U(t, q) - U(t, q))+delta, delta) = 0;
```

how can I get the epression in sup operator?
I have tried

```
indets(eq1, function);
select(has,eq1,delta);
```

but fails

what I want is to get

```
eq2:=h(delta)*(U(t, q - 1) - U(t, q)) + (1 - h(delta))*(U(t, q) - U(t, q))+delta
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
eq1 := diff(U(t, q), t)
       + lambda*sup(h(delta)*(U(t, q - 1) - U(t, q))
                    + (1 - h(delta))*(U(t, q) - U(t, q))+delta,
                    delta) = 0:

op( [1,1], indets(eq1,specfunc(sup)) );

        h(delta) (U(t, q - 1) - U(t, q)) + delta
```

Comment: Your answer contains code without explanation. It's better to include details about *how* your answer answers the question.